# as3 How to create a DropDownList (no XML)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm a newbie in AS3 and I'm doing some simple UI. I want to create a dropdown list with a couple of options. I have read a lot of tutorials with hundreds of lines for making a dropdown list. Really? A hundred lines for a dropdown list? I just want to create a simple kind of HTML SELECT. If you know a tutorial that will also work.

I'm really sorry for this kind of question, but I really don´t find any written in as3.

I have already checked the one that adobe is giving is its page [adobe reference for DropDownList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DropDownList.html) but that example is using XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure AS3 based Class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    import com.greensock.*;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;

    public class MouseOverMenu extends MovieClip {

        public var _sMouseOver:MovieClip;
        public var _sMenu:MovieClip;

        private var _menuTimer:Timer;
        private var _menuOpen:Boolean = false;

        public function MouseOverMenu():void {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function init(e:Event):void {

            _sMouseOver.buttonMode = true;
            _sMouseOver.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, showMenu, false, 0, true);
            _sMouseOver.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, startClose, false, 0, true);
            _sMouseOver.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, cancelClose, false, 0, true);

            _menuTimer = new Timer( 50 );
            _menuTimer.addEventListener ( TimerEvent.TIMER, doCloseMenu );

            _sMenu.visible = false;
            _sMenu.alpha = 0;
            _sMenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, startClose, false, 0, true);
            _sMenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, cancelClose, false, 0, true);
        }
        private function showMenu(e:MouseEvent):void {
            _menuOpen = true;
            _sMenu.visible = true;
            TweenLite.to(_sMenu, .5, {y:73, alpha:1});
        }
        private function startClose ( e:Event ):void {
            //trace('startClose ' + e.target);
            _menuTimer.start();
        }
        private function cancelClose ( e:Event ):void {
            //trace('cancelClose ' + e.target);
            _menuTimer.stop();
        }
        private function doCloseMenu ( e:Event ) {
            closeMenu();
        }
        private function closeMenu ():void {
            if ( _menuOpen ) {
                TweenLite.to(_sMenu, .5, {y:50, alpha:0, onComplete: hideMenu});
            }
            _menuTimer.stop();
            _menuOpen = false;
        }
        private function hideMenu():void {
            _sMenu.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I'm getting errors because I don't have com.greensock.* an also the TweenLite one. From where I can get the com.greensock? I'm totally new to flash & using flashdevelop. Asa I can include them in the project and check it I'll let you know the results. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @kitimenpolku Little tip with packages: Most people follow the reverse-domain format. So com.greensock is a package created by greensock.com. That is useful when trying to find a third party package and is also how you should structure your own package names

Answer (score 0):

I dont see an XML being used in the example mentioned by you, anyways this is a simple code for Dropdownlist in Flex which uses arrayCollection.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/03/07/using-the-dropdownlist-in-flex-gumbo/ -->
    <s:Application name="Spark_DropDownList_test"
            xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
        <s:layout>
            <s:BasicLayout />
        </s:layout>

        <s:DropDownList id="dropDownLst"
                requireSelection="true"
                horizontalCenter="0" top="20">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList source="[The,quick,brown,fox,jumps,over,the,lazy,dog]" />
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>

    </s:Application>
```

Comment: I meant without MXML tags. I said XML because in adobe documentation they explicitly say in the MXML Syntax section: "MXML is an XML language that you use to lay out user-interface components for Adobe® Flex®applications."

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by code if you don't want to use MXML:

```
yourDropDownInstance.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(["The","quick",
                                                         "brown","fox",
                                                         "jumps","over",
                                                         "the","lazy","dog"]);
```

Comment: Sure I created and added as follow: `var list:DropDownList = new DropDownList();list.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(["The","quick",
                                                         "brown","fox",
                                                         "jumps","over",
                                                         "the", "lazy", "dog"]);addChild(list);` . I dont see anything on the sprite. Why is it not displayed?

Comment: you can trace the size of the DDList you can check if ddList instance's stage property is not null (it is not null when it is added to stage or it's parent on stage).